# How to stop loading my custom scripts files for wordpress iframe?

Tags: php, wp-enqueue-script, embed

How to stop loading my custom scripts files for WordPress iframe?

In my site, i loading many of custom scripts and my problem that all of this scripts are loading with WordPress embed iframe posts and this cause a slow speed for sites that use my posts iframe, So how can check if it's not the iframe when I register custom scripts and styles?

Can I use if condition for something like this?

Comment: Do you mean the [embedded posts added in 4.4](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/10/28/new-embeds-feature-in-wordpress-4-4/), or do you just mean someone literally just adding an iframe tag with your posts url? Or are you doing something else?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Yes I mean embedded posts that added in 4.4, I want to be free to choose which scripts to load for embedded posts iframe.

Comment: As far as I can tell the only scripts that are loaded are the ones that are necessary for the embed to work. Normally enqueued scripts shouldn't load. There's a separate hook for that, `enqueue_embed_scripts`. You should be able to dequeue in that hook any scripts if you really need to.

Comment: @JacobPeattie i register my custom scripts and css files by: wp_enqueue_scripts and wp_print_styles i'am not using enqueue_embed_scripts hook.

Comment: And they’re showing up in the embed, or not in the embed?

Comment: Yes, they're loading in the iframe head (CSS files only) I found that scripts not loading only CSS files.